# Why is my ContourPlot cutting off at certain values?

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

I have

```
h[phi_, delta_] := ArcCos[-Tan[phi Degree] Tan[delta Degree]]
insolation[phi_, delta_, S_: 1368] := (S/Pi) (Cos[delta Degree] Cos[phi Degree] Sin[h] + h Sin[delta Degree] Sin[phi Degree]) /. h -> h[phi, delta]
ContourPlot[insolation[phi, 23.5 Cos[t]], {t, -Pi, Pi}, {phi, -90, 90},
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, ContourLabels -> False, Contours -> 20, 
    ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

But the resulting figure has areas that are "missing":

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the expected vertical contours extending from the truncated edges to the near horizontal axis in the upper center and bottom right and left corners? How to I "fill in" the regions in the upper right and left corners that are 0?

---

A similar figure for comparison:

[image]

Comment: @Kuba: How do I prevent my uploaded images from being HUGE when I upload Retina screenshots (maybe a meta question; this issue must have come up before)?

Comment: Make it a meta question and I'll reply.

Comment: That region of the contour plot is white because the expression `insolation[phi, 23.5 Cos[t]]` evaluates to non-real complex numbers at those `t,phi` points.  I tried this by right-clicking the plot, and using Get Coordinates to sample coordinates from that region, then putting them into the expression.

Comment: @Szabolcs: [Asked.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1259/37)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Is there a way to get what I'm seeking; e.g. by fixing `insolation`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You can wrap `insolation` with `Abs` or `Re`, depends of what the interpretation is. Also, add `PlotRange -> {0, 600}` then.

Comment: @Kuba: That's an answer: `Re` does the trick. What is the change to `PlotRange` for though?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius For safety :) who knows what those complex numers are :P

Comment: @Kuba I must leave now and I might forget when I come back ... feel free to post it yourself and include the PlotRange->All comment ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually such issue is caused by `Automatic` `Range` and `PlotRange->All` would be a fix. It's not the case though.

[Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) has noticed:

> That region of the contour plot is white because the expression `insolation[phi, 23.5 Cos[t]]` evaluates to non-real complex numbers at those `t`, `phi` points. I tried this by right-clicking the plot, and using `GetCoordinates` to sample coordinates from that region, then putting them into the expression.

So the quick fix is to take only a real part:

```
ContourPlot[
 Re@insolation[phi, 23.5 Cos[t]], {t, -Pi, Pi}, {phi, -90, 90}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ContourLabels -> False, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

> [image]

Keep in mind that `PlotRange` issue could be still a case here, but it isn't :).

Also, this is quick fix, but at the end one should think what taking a real part means for us here or what does it mean our function produced complex values.